# If $f(x) = |x|^3$, show $f'''(0)$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, absolute-value

If $f(x) = |x|^3$, show $f'''(0)$ does not exist.

So I've computed the first, second and third derivatives, so

$f'(x) = 3x|x|$

$f''(x) = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if x = 0} \\
\frac{6x^2}{|x|}, & \text{if x $\ne$ 0}
\end{cases}$

$f'''(x) = \frac{6x^3}{|x|^3}$.

I know if I were to simply plug  in $0$ for $x$, I would end up with $\frac{0}{0} = 0$, but that doesn't bring me to the $DNE$ conclusion. Is this someplace I should be using L'Hopital's Rule? The question didn't use the word "limit", but it's the only option I can come up with...

Comment: You need to use limits, the problem is the absolute value is - on the left and + on the right, so the two limits won't agree (This isn't a problem on the first or second derivative since they are squeezed by an extra power of x

Comment: What expression did you obtain for $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$? You need to show that $f''$ is not differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: What is the point of tagging "$\forall x\in \Bbb{R}$" onto the end of your question, when the statement is not about a variable called $x$ but about $0$?

Comment: What exactly is $f''(x)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown edited to show

Comment: Why not write $6|x|$ rather than $6x^2/|x|$?

Answer (score 1):

Most straightforward is to say:

$f(x) = \begin{cases} -x^3 & x < 0\\x^3 & x\ge 0 \end{cases}$

The derivatives of $f$ will have the same piece-wise structure.

$f'''(x)$ will appear to have a jump discontinuity.

The derivative is defined as a limit, if the left hand limit does not equal the right hand limit, the limit does not exist.  The derivative does not exist at the point of this jump.

Comment: I didn't think about splitting it like that from the start.. thank you it's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hopital rule we have that
$$lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{ f{''}(x)}{x}=12$$ and $$lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{ f{''}(x)}{x}=-12$$

So the third derivative at $0$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of $f(x)=|x|^3$ as composite function $f(x)=(g\circ h)(x)$ with $g(x)=x^3$ and $h(x)=|x|$. By chain rule if at a point $x=c$ the function $h$ is differentiable and $g$ is differentiable at $h(c)$ then $f'(c)=g'(h(c))h'(c)$. But at $c=0$ we have that $h$ is not differentiable since $h'(0^-)=-1\neq 1=h'(0^+)$. As consequence $f$ is not differentiable at $c=0$. Surely then the third derivative doesn't exist there for it requires the first derivative to exist in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first establish a lemma:

> Given any function $g : (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$. If $g'(0)$ exists , then$\color{blue}{{}^{[1]}}$
>   $$\mathcal{J}(g) \stackrel{def}{=} \lim_{h\to 0+} \frac{g(2h)-g(h) + g(-2h) - g(-h)}{h} = 0$$

Let's say $g'(0)$ exists and equals to $L$, we have

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(2h)-g(h)}{h} = 
\lim_{h\to 0} \left[2\left(\frac{g(2h)-g(0)}{2h}\right) - \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}
\right] = 2L - L = L
$$
This implies
$$\mathcal{J}(g) = \lim_{h\to 0+} \left[\frac{g(2h)-g(h)}{h} - \frac{g(-2h)-g(-h)}{-h}\right] = L - L = 0$$
and justify the lemma.

Back to original problem. 
Since $f(x)$ is smooth for $x \ne 0$, it is easy to deduce
$f''(x) = 6|x|$ for $x \ne 0$. By direct computation, we have

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{J}(f'') &= \lim_{h\to 0+} \frac{f''(2h)-f''(h) + f''(-2h) - f''(-h)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0+} \frac{6|2h| - 6|h| + 6|-2h| - 6|-h|}{h}\\
&= 12
\end{align}$$
Since $\mathcal{J}(f'') \ne 0$, by above lemma, $f'''(0)$ does not exist.

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - $\mathcal{J}(g)$ is the size of jump discontinuity of $g'(x)$ at $x = 0$. The whole point of this complicated mess is to have a formula for the jump in $f''(x)$ at $x = 0$ without explicit referral to values of $f(0)$, $f'(0)$, $f''(0)$ and $f'''(0)$ which are clumsy to describe and justify.

Comment: Dear Teacher, dear Professor  I'm so sorry for this comment..I know that this is so wrong..Then I will delete this comment.I ask a question in MSE. But everyone thinks the question is nonsense. Because, anybody could not even write a comment..But this is not a homework..So I admit that it might be nonsense..Teacher, please tell me the problem is really nonsense, I will delete it immediately. If I would like to ask can you look a question, if you have a few minutes.Thank you very much.(English is my second language, I'm sorry for wrong words)  
 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2765611/548054

Comment: @Beginner I look at that question, it only contains a bunch of sequences. From the sequences, there is no way to  know what those numbers means. This stops one from building models for them and perform any statistical analysis. At the least, you could state clearly how the numbers are generated, what sort of model is underlying their generation (even a wild guess) before anyone can follow up.

Comment: I appreciate you coming back..So the question was not answered because it was not known how the numbers were produced. I understood you. I just cautioned that the graphics were getting stuck in the $Oy$ arrow. I thought there was a connection between the charts/Graphics..I tried to do a statistical analysis. (By myself..)..

Comment: @Beginner strictly speaking, what is missing is what are those numbers, what are they stand for and why are they interesting. One way to assist other to understand the numbers is tell people  how the numbers are generated.

Comment: You are completely right. I will do what you say...

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} -x^3 & x < 0\\x^3 & x\ge 0 \end{cases}\Rightarrow f'(x)=\begin{cases} -3x^2=3x(-x) & x < 0\\3x^2=3x(x) & x\ge 0 \end{cases}\iff f'(x)=3x|x|$$
$$f^{''}(x)=\begin{cases} -6x & x < 0\\6x & x\ge 0 \end{cases}\iff f^{''}(x)=6|x|$$ It follows that the tangents are constantly $-6$ at the left of $0$ and constantly $6$ at the right of $0$ so $f^{''}(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$.

NOTE.-You can verify, for example, drawing the graphics that $6|x|=\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if x = 0} \\
\dfrac{6x^2}{|x|}, & \text{if x $\ne$ 0}
\end{cases}$.

I mean your expression and mine are equivalent.